# given a success probability calculate the associated participants number

Tags: probability

I have

- a pool of participants - given
- number of tournaments (competitions) -given
- participants per tournament

A number of participants is selected from the pool, and from this resulting subgroup the best 1 is removed. All other participants from the subgroup go back into the pool. This is one tournament.
I have to repeat it according to the number of tournaments.

I have calculated the probability of a specific participant (the one with highest ranking in the whole pool) being picked using a loop (as I didn't know the formula and in the end need to code this anyhow).

Just for info, I did it this way:
Add all tournament results to a SUM:
1st tournament: [1/(pool)+1/(pool-1)+....+1/(pool-participants)]+
...+...+..
last tournament: [1/(pool-tournaments+1)+.....+1/(pool-tournaments+1-participants)] (**EDIT:** this is wrong, correct proposals see in the answers below)

I think this is ok, AND I would like to also **calculate how many participants** I need per tournament to have a given probability i.e. of 100% of picking a specific participant met.

Any insights are highly welcome!
Thanks

**EDIT 28.7.2017**
THIS WORKS, but is really slow, so if there is some way of simplyfing the formula for M, that would be amazing

```
    var minTourParticipants = 0;
var probabilityOfNotBeingPicked = 1;

do{
    minTourParticipants++;
    probabilityOfNotBeingPicked = 1;

    //run tournaments
    for(var i = 0; i < tournaments; i++){ 
        probabilityOfNotBeingPicked = probabilityOfNotBeingPicked*(pool-(i)-minTourParticipants)/(pool-i);
        if(probabilityOfNotBeingPicked === 0){
            break;
        }

    }

}while((1-probabilityForParticipant) < probabilityOfNotBeingPicked);
```

Comment: If you're just looking for the best participant, and assuming that being a better participant is a transitive relation, then why even bother replacing the "losers" back into the pool?

Comment: I think that in your big SUM you forgot to exclude the cases when your champion has already been picked in one of the previous tournaments. As a consequence, your probability may very well exceed 1.

Comment: @Linnell: because for calculation speed I am "randomly" picking the best guys, to create a new "winner" pool, rather then sorting the whole pool and then pick them, but I would like to ensure the that top, of the top has been picked with a given probability

Comment: @Evargalo: you are right! thanks for the explanation below!

Answer (score 0):

Let's fix:

- $N$ the total number of participants
- $T$ the number of tournaments
- $M<N-T$ the number of players per tournament (assuming this is a constant)

Then the probability for the champion to be picked in the first tournament is $p_1=M/N$.

The probability for him to be picked in the 2d tournament (means he must not have been chosen in the first one!) is $p_2=(1-p_1)\frac{M}{N-1}$

The probability for him to be picked in the $t$-th tournament is $p_t=(1-p_{t-1})\frac{M}{N-t}$

The probability for the champion to be picked at all is $P=\sum_{t=1}^Tp_t$

But the easiest is to look for the probability of him NOT been picked:

$1-P=\prod_{t=0}^{T-1}\frac{N-t-M}{N-t}$

$P=1-\prod_{t=0}^{T-1}\frac{N-t-M}{N-t}$

$P=1-\frac{(N-M)!}{T!}\frac{(N-T)!}{N!}$

$P=1-\frac{(N-M)!(N-T)!}{T!N!}$

*Edit:*

Now if you're looking for the maximal $N$ in order for $P$ to be at a given level, it is easy to solve the previous result for $N$ knowing $P$ with an algorithm, but I don't se any closed form solution.

If you're looking for the minimal $M$ in order for $P$ to be at a given level, you notice that $1-P=\frac{(N-M)!(N-T)!}{T!N!}$

So for your algorithm you don't have to actually compute big factorials, you just start by computing $(N-T)!/(T!N)$ and compare with $1-P$, if need be you multiply by $1/(N-1)$, then $1/(N-2)$ and so on.

Comment: YOU ARE A GENIUS!!! I completely missed that ... well it is about 20 years ago I did this the last time :). Yes, you are completely right, I need to correct my calculation. I can do it with your great explanation (the last formula is over my head :) ). I also believe that by reordering the formula for M I can find a solution to my question.... will give it a shot and come back if I get stuck :)

Comment: I am actually looking for solving it for M. N is always given and I know what T has to be (given by external factors). Is there a way for M?

Comment: I was able to implement the formula pt=(1−pt−1)M/(N−t) into a loop. I tried the factorial first, but given that my N can be up to 20.000, my computer refused any cooperation (already with 200). I am stuck at getting to M though. Any further thoughts, that you could share? Or do you mean by algorithm, just throwing random numbers at the formula and see if you are getting closer or further away.

Comment: Sorry, but I am confused by 1−P=(N−M)!/N!=1/N*1/(N−1)...1/(N−M+1). Can you maybe elaborate a little more. Because if I take P=10% and N=10....I have on the left side 0.9 and on the right 0.1... and 1/10 is exactly 10%, but it does not equate.. What am I missing here? And why is there no T impact. I see that it falls out in the formula prior edit, but it feels wrong, that all is independent of the number of tournaments...?

Comment: hmmm. You're rigth, it is weirded that T has dropped. I'll look again tonight, but I lack time right now.

Comment: I have run a few number tests and I believe that 1−P=∏T−1 t=0 (N−t−M)/(N−t) is correct and that t should not drop. It only drops with a generic formula for 1 tournament

Comment: I've corrected the formula. $T$ remains, of course, but since $M$ appears only once the algorithm shouldn't be difficult to write.

Comment: I have in the mean time written an algorithm (though it is slower than I want). See in my initial question as edit. I have now also tested the updated formula, but that still does not seem correct. I have tested a few numbers on the paper and the results are strange.

Comment: Here an example why I believe the last formula still has issues. I take N=10, T=1 M=1 so should get 0.9 for 1-P. yet I get (10-1)!(10-1)!/(1!*10!)=9!*9!/10!=362880*362880/3628800=36288

Answer (score 0):

Let's make a slight generalization.  Think of the pool as $a$ people who are good, $b$ who are average, and $c$ who are bad.  We want to compute the probability $p(a,b,c,k,t)$ of at least one average person winning one of the $t$ tournaments, with $k$ participants per tournament.  We require $a+b+c \ge k+t-1$ so that every tournament has the required $k$ participants.

Clearly $p(a,b,c,k,0) = 0$:  if there are no participants, there are no winners.

The recursion for $p$ may be expressed as follows:
\begin{align}
p(a,b,c,k,t) = \Bigg(
&\left(\binom{a+b+c}{k} - \binom{b+c}{k} \right) p(a-1,b,c,k,t-1) \; + \\
&\left(\binom{b+c}{k} - \binom{c}{k} \right) \cdot 1\; +\\
&\;\;\binom{c}{k} \; p(a,b,c-1,k,t-1)
\Bigg)\bigg/\binom{a+b+c}{k}.
\end{align}

To justify this recursion, note that the difference of binomial coefficients in the first line counts the ways that a tournament could have a good person.  In such a case, a good person is removed from the pool, but there is one fewer tournament.  Similarly, in the second line the difference counts the ways that a tournament could have an average person but no good person.  In such a case, the probability of at least one average person winning a tournament is 1.  The last line accounts for the case of all bad people in a tournament.

To solve the problem stated, suppose $n$ denotes the size of the participant pool and we are interested in the probability of the $j^{th}$ best person being among the victors.  This probability may be expressed $p(j-1,1,n-j,k,t)$.

For example, here is a plot of the probabilities of the $j^{th}$ best person being picked out of a pool of 100 with 20 tournaments of 10 people each, for $j = 1$ to $60$.

[image: probabilities of being picked]

**Edit:** The picture is not showing up for some reason (first time I've tried to post one), but here's the Mathematica code that implements the recursion above.  It's pretty straightforward provided you're using a language that supports recursion.

```
p[a_, b_, c_, k_, 0] := 0;
p[a_, b_, c_, k_, t_] := p[a, b, c, t, k] =
   ((Binomial[a + b + c, k] - Binomial[b + c, k]) p[a - 1, b, c, k, t - 1] +
    (Binomial[b + c, k] - Binomial[c, k]) 1 +
     Binomial[c, k] p[a, b, c - 1, k, t - 1])/Binomial[a + b + c, k];
```

For example, the probability of the the third best person being picked (out of a pool of 100 with 20 tournaments of 10 people each) is

```
p[2,1,97,10,20]
```

which gives the result

```
7641626974773994684341551557/8631114035410540271032419432
```

which is approximately $0.885358$.

Comment: Thank you very much Jim, yet this is too high for my understanding. I am looking for practical implementation into code and I struggle with translating the formula into my basic understanding.

Comment: Okay.  I added my code in case that helps.